# Need suggestions on JavaScript recursion and async methods

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I have a recursive method that has, contained within, a async method:

```
var loadWebsRecursively = function (url) {

    loadWebsDeferred(url).then(function (webs) {

        var wE = webs.getEnumerator();
        webCount += webs.get_count();
        while (wE.moveNext()) {
            var site = wE.get_current();
            var title = site.get_title().toLowerCase();
            var fqdn = siteRootUrl + site.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '/';
            .... // additional work
        }

         webProcessed++;
         loadWebsRecursively(fqdn);
    }
};
```

I need some suggestions on how I can determine that all recursive calls have finished. Each Web could have "N" number of sub-webs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: M Quickel - Did you determine a solution for this? Have a similar situation for a cascade delete where i don't know in advance how many children and to what depth I am dealing with.

Comment: Think I can rework this concept for DB tree walking ops - http://grammerjack.blogspot.jp/2010/12/asynchronous-directory-tree-walk-in.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking to resolve a promise sequence. If you're using javascript's native ES6 promise implementation, then something like the following might be what you're looking for:

```
// Loop through our chapter urls
story.chapterUrls.reduce(function(sequence, chapterUrl) {
  // Add these actions to the end of the sequence
  return sequence.then(function() {
    return getJSON(chapterUrl);
  }).then(function(chapter) {
    addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
  });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

See here for more details:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing

Comment: I'm using the jQuery deferred library. I think the problem with resolution is that I have an unknown number of promises. For example, if I knew that I had 20 items in my hierarchy I could build all of my promises up front and then check for their completion using .when(). In my case, a new promise is not being added to my promise collection until the recursive function's callback happens again so I am consistently checking for resolution against a moving target.

Comment: Agreed, the problem is trivial if you know the sequence you are dealing with in advance.